# Pick random file from a folder containing folders, then files

Tags: javascript

My site's idea revolves around users receiving random results, where some are better than others. My results are split into 7 tiers, and there are a few of them in each tier.

I want my code to randomly pick a tier, then randomly pick a file from within the tier, i am then going to display the tier, and name of file.

However what i'm trying at the minute isn't exactly working, and seems very un-optimal.

If possible i would like to retain file names as it makes them easier to display the results later. My results are images and are hosted server-side in an images folder. The file structure looks like:

index-tier 1-7 folders-files

Comment: Nice, do you have a question?

Comment: _"however what i'm trying at the minute isn't exactly working, and seems very un-optimal."_ Can you include `javascript` tried at Question ? Can you describe "isn't exactly working" ?

Comment: Sorry, i dont use stack overflow much, made an account today.

My question is how can i select a random folder and then select a random file from that folder with javascript? As well as display information such as folder name and file name

Comment: Are you interfacing with a server-side language?

Comment: What else than picking a random value from an array do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using `Math.floor()` , `Math.random()`, `Image`

```
var tiers = 7;

var min = 1;

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (tiers - min + 1)) + min;

var folder = "/path/to/index-tier" + rand;

var files = 14;

var curr = Math.floor(Math.random() * (files - min + 1)) + min;

var file = "/path/to/folders-files" + curr;

var img = new Image;

img.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.body.appendChild(this)
});

img.src = folder + file;
```